# Google Sheets - Sum of values from multiple cells depending on text in corresponding cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I couldn't figure this out despite digging so hopefully someone here will know what to do. I have a large sheet for a project I'm working on and I'd like to automate a bit of it if possible, since there's so many cells to manage.

I need at least three things for several different small areas of the project, which I'd like to be picked from a material list on the side.

It currently works like this:

```
      B                 C                D                 E
2 Project Name |  Material #01  |  Material #02  | Material #03   |
3              |Quantity needed |Quantity needed |Quantity needed |
```

This pattern continues all the way up until line 50 and I have it laid out across multiple columns for space efficiency. [The above example is also on H2:K3]

Off to the right side I have a place to keep up with the materials this is referencing, like such:

```
       M               N            O           P
2 Material #01 | Material Name | # I have | # I need
3 Material #03 | Material Name | # I have | # I need
```

This is also in double sections, with the even numbers on S2:W3.

What I want to accomplish is if, say - C2, E2, and D12 all contain "Material #01", it will grab the number in the cell below, being C3, E3, and D13, then add them up and place the final number in P2 as the amount I need. However, I need this to be a thing I don't have to manually change, so I want it to detect if I were to change C2 to "Material #03" and then place the sum into P3 instead.

Can this be done? I can add more information or clarify anything upon request. I just haven't made much headway into figuring this out on my own. If this has been answered, please forgive me, I've been throwing every way of wording I could think of to try searching for this, but it's possible I've missed something obvious like a clownshoe.

Comment: can you please add a sample sheet  - you can have dummy data in it but to accurately answer need to see a sample of the conditions we are actually working with

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fRAA9uDdu_xOLDsCoAHKhuOe7hDQXpIlYHxjYBndM6U/edit?usp=sharing Here's a copy. The rows changed a little since I posted this, but it's over all the same thing. I want columns P and V to be automatically added as I put them in on the right area, if at all possible!

Answer (score 0):

**Good Solution**

I suppose, best way for you is to organize your data properly. This means, paste data in simple table:

```
Project Name    Product Number  Quantity needed
Project1        #01                           1
Project1        #02                           2
Project1        #03                           1
Project2        #11                           5
Project2        #07                           6
Project2        #14                           6
```

Paste this values in range A:C and then just use one of multiple Google sheet data manipulation formulas, like query:

```
=QUERY({A:C},"select Col2, sum(Col3) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2")
```

I've added [Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t2bCfgwAnGHXYGvYQXyYztmaVoSTMVM3h6_31lBGqeo/edit#gid=992706190)

---

**Solution As it is**

Your case is very specific and the final formula is error-prone and hard to read.

Paste this formula in cell P2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L2:L49,QUERY({query(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:J,iseven(row(C2:J)))&"-")),"-")),"where Col1 like '#%' limit "&counta(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:J,ISODD(row(C2:J)))&"-")),"-")))),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:J,ISODD(row(C2:J)))&"-")),"-"))},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1"),2,0)))
```

and this formula in cell V2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R2:R49,QUERY({query(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:J,iseven(row(C2:J)))&"-")),"-")),"where Col1 like '#%' limit "&counta(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:J,ISODD(row(C2:J)))&"-")),"-")))),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(FILTER(C2:J,ISODD(row(C2:J)))&"-")),"-"))},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1"),2,0)))
```

they will expand automatically.

how it works: please [look at example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t2bCfgwAnGHXYGvYQXyYztmaVoSTMVM3h6_31lBGqeo/edit#gid=0). Feel free to ask any questions about the formula.

Both formulas are looking for ranges `L2:L49` and `R2:R49`. Change them to yours if needed.

Comment: The problem with this is it takes up a lot of space vertically and I would really prefer not doing that. You also left out the repeat materials that crop up all the time as I've shown in my example which doesn't help much on the front of showing it truly in action. I thought about doing something like this but again the space it takes up is the only problem since I have a lot of things to keep straight so I need to see as much as I can as fast as I can. I'll probably mess around some more if it's my only option, or just continue putting it in manually.